# Updating JS to work with IE10

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I've been given the task of updating some Javascript for IE10. I've searched endlessly for a solution, but I just can't seem to find one. The piece of code I'm stuck at is:

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
this.svgDoc = document.getElementById("SVGDoc").getSVGDocument();
this.grp = this.svgDoc.createElementNS(svgns, "g");
this.grp.setAttribute("id", this.id);

if (this.parent)
    this.svgDoc.getElementById(this.parent.id).appendChild(this.grp);
else
    this.svgDoc.getDocumentElement.appendChild(this.grp);
```

The last line is where it fails, giving me the error *Unable to get property `appendChild` of undefined or null reference*. I can't seem to figure out why it is a null reference as it worked with IE8 and lower.

Comment: Change getDocumentElement to getDocumentElement()

Comment: This may explain why i'm having trouble. This code wasn't write by me so, as you probably know, i'm having a hard time reading it.

Comment: I'm now getting the error Object doesn't support property or method 'getDocumentElement'

Comment: Try `this.svgDoc.ownerSVGElement`.

Comment: I've tried this.svgDoc.ownerSVGElement.appendChild and this.svgDoc.ownerSVGElement.getDocumentElement().appendChild neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getDocumentElement should be just [documentElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-87CD092) Works on pretty much all version of IE according to [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html)

Comment: I know, that's my area of expertise :-)

Comment: Ah, OK. I did not see any SVG mentioned in the DOM list

Comment: It's not SVG specific, it works on any XML document, SVG is just one example of such.

Comment: This seems to have worked! Just got some more errors now to fix due to IE10.